# Is HTML searchable?

Tags: android, html, xhtml

is HTML &/ xHTML within the res / assets folder searchable @ run time like XML?
Thnx!

Comment: Searchable? You mean like pressing ctrl+h in eclipse? or ..

Comment: You say 'like XML' could you show how you do it for XML? Because 'Searchable' is a bit vague :-)

Comment: Oh, I get it know; Location:UK Age:24.  Dude!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read any asset with the `AssetManager` and then do whatever you please with it... like piping it into an XML parser.